# shell: The =~ operator does not work as expected

Tags: bash, regular-expression, test

Consider the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash

line="confusing"

if [[ $line =~ [[:lower:]]* ]]
then
    echo "matches!"
else
    echo "does not match."
fi
```

While the above produce the expected result, the following does not:

```
#! /bin/bash

line="CoNfUsInG"

if [[ $line =~ [[:lower:]]* ]]
then
    echo "matches!"
else
    echo "does not match."
fi
```

This prints "matches!"
I am confused; isn't the regular expression `[[:lower:]]*` means zero or more lower case letters?

It gets even more confusing when the following also prints "matches!"

```
#! /bin/bash

line="CoNfUsInG"

if [[ $line =~ [[:digit:]]* ]]
then
    echo "matches!"
else
    echo "does not match."
fi
```

Anyone have an explanation to why this happens?

Comment: The key is "**zero** or more characters" -- there are zero lower/digit characters right at the beginning of that string.

Comment: the regexp isn't anchored with `^` so there are *zero-or-more* matches anywhere in the string, not just at the beginning.   Also, OP can use `+` instead of `*` if they want *1-or-more* matches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The regular expression doesn't have to match the whole string. That's why you have `^` and `$` for string beginning and end, respectively.

```
[[ CoNfUsInG =~ ^[[:lower:]]*$ ]] || echo no
```

CoNfUsInGlY, `^[[:lower:]]*` (without the `$`) still matches, as there are zero lower-case letters at the beginning of the string.

Comment: `^[[:lower:]]*$` also matches the empty string.  Use `^[[:lower:]]+$` if you want to match on *at least one* lowercase char in the string.

Comment: @cas your RE `^[[:lower:]]+$` will match only if the string consists _entirely_ of lowercase letters and it is not zero length.

Comment: yes, that's what i said.